# whats the difference between for loop with select and only select?

Tags: go, goroutine

Could not fully understand it from the docs or google:

What are the differences between the two and in 
Which case would you use each one?

```
    for{
       select{
       case s := <-something:
           fmt.Println(s)
       case done := <-true:
           return 
       }
    }
```

and

```
       select{
       case s := <-something:
           fmt.Println(s)
       case done := <-true:
           return 
       }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Code with loop will **keep printing** data from channel `something` **until** it receives anything on channel `done`.

Select-only code will **either** print data from channel `something` **or** will quit when it receives anything on channel `done`. **Only one case** will be executed. Keep in mind there is no fallthrough in Go `select` and `switch` statements by default.

Answer (score 4):

`select` statement executes through its `cases` (sending/receiving a the channel) once. If none of its cases are ready to be executed, it blocks until at least one of the `case` is ready to execute. If more than one cases are ready at the same time, one of the ready case is selected to be executed at random.

So in second case, if there is some data on the `something` channel, it would be read and put into `s`. But there is also a chance of `true` being sent on `done` while the  `case s := <-something:` will never be executed.

In the first case, you probably want something like this (also in second case):

```
for{
   select{
   case s := <-something:
       fmt.Println(s)
   case <-done: // note the difference
       return 
   }
}
```

What this now does is that it waits for data on `something` and also keeps an eye on `done`. If there is data on `something` channel (and no data on `done`), it will be read and put into `s` (case branch `case s := <-something:` will be executed with `s` having the value read from `something`). This will account for one full execution of `select` statement and the control will go back to `for` loop and it will start over again.

If there is no data on `something` channel, `select` blocks and waits for data on either `something` or `done`. If data arrives on `something`, similar execution as above happens, otherwise if it arrives in `done`, the function returns (breaks out of loop). This way some other process can write to `done` and signal the function containing above `for` loop to stop processing `something` and return.

Answer (score 1):

If your program sends data to the 'something' channel a bunch of times you are going to want to repeat the select clause until you receive a done signal.

For example imagine you are running the following routine

```
.... (some calculations)
something <- x 
.... (some calculations)
something <- y
true <- z
```

If your routine doesn't have the for loop it will only receive the value 'x' and won't receive y or z.